# how can i re-write the below code to get an actual data set instead of the empty data frame response that i am getting?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, python-requests

### I have written the following lines of code to *scrape* a book store website to get; the book title, the price of the book and the availability of the book. My code runs well but i get an empty data frame instead of the data i want. Please assist

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> import re
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> full_dict={'Title':[],'Price':[],'Availability':[]}
>>> for index in range(1,50):
    res=requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/category/books_1/index?={index}.html")
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    books=soup.find_all(class_='product_prod')
    for book in books:
        book_title=book.find(href=re.compile("title"))
        book_price=book.find('div',{'class':'product_price'})
        book_availability=book.find('p',{'class':'instock.availability'})
        full_dict['Title'].append(title)
        full_dict['Price'].append(price)
        full_dict['Availability'].append(availability)

        
>>> df=pd.DataFrame(full_dict)
>>> print(df)
```

### i want to get the book title,book price and book availability(whether the book in in stock) displayed as results. form http://books.toscrape.com/index.html, for the first 50 pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I just saw the mistake:

your variables are called e.g. `book_title`
but you append just `title`

it must be:

```
full_dict['Title'].append(book_title)
full_dict['Price'].append(book_price)
full_dict['Availability'].append(book_availability)
```

Comment: now i do not get the empty data frame error. Now i get empty columns.

Comment: can you post an example of the dict you are using? I can't reproduce the error because I'm getting the 404 error with opening the html pages

Comment: http://books.toscrape.com/index.html. I want to scrap details of the book title, price and book availability for the first 50 pages

Comment: code from @QHarr works, also you had a spelling error with `product_prod` instead of `product_pod`

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your url to be correct otherwise 404. I would then also change to faster selectors and ensure your variable names are consistent

```
import requests
import bs4

full_dict={'Title':[],'Price':[],'Availability':[]}

for index in range(1,3):
    res = requests.get(f"http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{index}.html") #http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-2.html
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
    books = soup.select('.product_pod')

    for book in books:
        book_title = book.select_one('h3 a').text
        book_price = book.select_one('.price_color').text.replace('Â','')
        book_availability = book.select_one('.availability').text.strip()
        full_dict['Title'].append(book_title)
        full_dict['Price'].append(book_price)
        full_dict['Availability'].append(book_availability)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're getting an 404 Error from the Webpage

Comment: no it's not a 404 error. What i get in the console is this:"Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Price, Availability]
Index: []"

Comment: but do you get any data out of e.g. `soup`?